# Synaptic not adding downloaded packages

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, synaptic

I'm using Synaptic 0.83 on Ubuntu 16.04 to install downloaded debs to my laptop from another laptop, lately adding the packages would copy them to the directory

```
var/cache/apt/archives
```

but it doesn't do anything!

Could anyone help? I have a lot of packages to install and a limited data plan, and the dependences are just too much to handle!

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple to fix, all you have to do is to update the packages cache, you can do that by going to the "Software and updates" and making any small change, if you don't know what to do just uncheck something, enter your password and check it back again, you will be prompted to reload your packages.
Once done, you will be able to use Synaptic like normal again!

Comment: That was the answer I needed! Thank you so much man!